# Django: Save duplicate of an instance along with relationships

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to save duplicate of an instance along with all direct and reverse relationships

I have used the following code

```
instance.id=None
instance.pk=None
instance.save()
```

By doing so, I am able to save all the attributes of the instance along with all the direct relationships and even reverse Foreign key relationship but I am not able to save the reverse one to one field relationship.

Comment: How can you clone something and keep a 1-to-1 relationship? Wouldn't that make it 2-to-1? In any case, you need to add more detail to your question.

Comment: For a reverse Foreign Key relationship, a new entry is created for the new record, but not for reverse one to one relationship. I want to create a new one to one relationship for the new record

Comment: So A and B are in a 1-to-1 relationship, and you want to clone A to make C which is also in a 1-to-1 relationship with B? That would leave B in a 1-to-1 relationship with both A and C, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Actually I am using the same in django and want to save a new row in database for the one to one relationship